# modification for Immutable array not working

Tags: java, arrays, immutability

Modified the code for making the array immutable, but its getting wrong somewhere.As in the code, when  object created for ImmutableClassWithArray, the list is being initialised with given array.  Inside getter, unmodifiedable list is being returned converting to array. After then the array is modified. Even though, array has been altered after the constructor is called means after the list already initialised with some values, still the final array is getting reflected with the updated value.

```
public final class ImmutableClassWithArray {

    private final Integer[] arr= {1,2,3,4};
    List<Integer> list;

    public ImmutableClassWithArray() {
        this.list = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(arr));
    }

    public Integer[] getArr() {
        return (Integer[]) this.list.toArray();   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImmutableClassWithArray ob = new ImmutableClassWithArray();
        System.out.println("list value after copying array "+ob.list.get(2));
        ob.arr[2]=5;        
        System.out.println("arr value after modified "+ob.arr[2]);

        Integer[] a = ob.getArr();
        System.out.println("a value -  "+a[2]);

    }
}
```

output :->

list value after copying array 3

arr value after modified 5

a value -  5

Integer[] a = ob.getArr(); should return the original value of array because the list has been initialised before the value being altered.
But as in output getting as 'a value -  5' it should be 'a value -  3'.

Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: `Arrays.asList` is just a *view* of an array. You can still modify the underlying array. `Collections.unmodifiableList` is just an immutable *view* of another List, you can still modify the underlying list. There is no way to make an immutable array.

Comment: I know its kind of hack, trying to do here. my doubt is basically, array altered after when the list was already initialised. Still the final array which is derived from initial list, how its getting updated with altered value of array.

Answer (score 2):

Note that *unmodifiable* isn't the same as *immutable*.

There is nothing you can do to an immutable thing to modify its state.

There is nothing you can do to an unmodifiable thing to modify its state, *through that thing's interface*. However, if you have access to the data by some other means, e.g. you have direct access to the backing array, you can modify that, and observe the changes through the unmodifiable list.

Answer (score 1):

Making your array `final` does not make its contents immutable. It is only saying that the array reference itself cannot change.

Wrapping it in an `unmodifiableList` just means that whoever has a reference to that `List` cannot do an update *through that `List` interface*.

However, if you have access to the array (as you are doing) you can still change its contents, and the unmodifiable view will be updated accordingly (it is just a wrapper, not a copy).

If you want the contents of the array to be protected you have to close all access to it (make it private, and do not allow any methods of your object to change its values in any way.)

One small other thing to note is that you are doing  `Integer[] a = ob.getArr();` after you do the update to the array. So the new array instance being created from the unmodifiable list with `toArray()` is actually reflecting the updated values.